# Can't force IE8 to use IE8 mode

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie8-browser-mode

I tried to use:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

And my website still opens (I am using IE8) in `IE8 compat mode` with `Document Mode IE7 Standards (Page default)` - when I manually check to use IE8 standards website renders correctly - how I can force my page to use IE8 standards as default? This meta header seems not to working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution - it was caused by this code from html5boilerplate:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

It has to be just `<html>`.

It is strange that code in html5boilerplate causes IE7 standards...